# Regex replace strings matching pattern with multiple charercters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, handlebars.js

I have a string like this

`const str = "Today is going to be @[City Temp](city-temp) in @[City Name](city-name)"`

I want the output to be in handlebars syntax eg

`const str = "Today is going to be {{city-temp}} in {{city-name}}"`

I am having trouble trying to match this pattern.

I can see that if I do

`str.replace(/[()]/g,"")`

I get the string without the brackets.

But I can't work out how to search for the whole pattern something like the below where I find anything starting with `@[` and ending with `)`, I don't want to just start with `@` by itself as there may be times in the string I don't want to remove the `@` where it is not followed by a `[`

`/[\@\[A-Za-z0-9\](A-Za-z0-9-)`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you got this awkward `@[City Temp](city-temp)` format from

Comment: it come from a react library that allows you to automplete items like how you can mention people in SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
str = str.replace(/@\[[^\][]*]\(([^()]*)\)/g, "{{$1}}")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ifl1J4/1). *Details*:

- `@\[` - a `@[` string
- `[^\][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]\(` - a `](` string
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const str = "Today is going to be @[City Temp](city-temp) in @[City Name](city-name)"
console.log(str.replace(/@\[[^\][]*]\(([^()]*)\)/g, "{{$1}}"))
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down like this as well to improve my understanding of regex.